# postgresql call function with wrong params

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I declared postgresql function as follows, **this function simply calculate distance between 2 points in kmeter**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_places(ref refcursor,lat float8,lon float8, radius double precision) RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM place p where ST_Distance(ST_Point(lon,lat)::geography,ST_Point(p.lon,p.lat)::geography) <= radius;    -- Open a cursor
  RETURN ref;                                                        
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Calling is as follows:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT show_places('cities_cur',44.379,-79.703,255621.82229418);
FETCH ALL IN "cities_cur";
COMMIT;
```

But i faced this SQL exception:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is getting confuse over same names of variable and table column. just change the names of variables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_places(ref refcursor,v_lat float8,v_lon float8, radius double precision) RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM place p where ST_Distance(ST_Point(v_lon,v_lat)::geography,ST_Point(p.lon,p.lat)::geography) <= radius;    -- Open a cursor
  RETURN ref;                                                        
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```